# Intercom "Couldn't send" error, 404 from the /reply call

Tags: intercom

Getting these errors from intercom when we try to test it out -

[image]

Can't find anything in a google search or their docs

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I had a script blocking extension turned on in Chrome (Ghostery, in my case). Adding the site to the trusted list within Ghostery fixed it for me.